# Calculate the complexity of the function, hw in python

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.x, time-complexity

I need to calculate the running time complexity of the function in terms of n (for exmaple O(n)), 
n is len(lst) , lst is a variable of list type.

[image: ques1]

this is what I thought, is it right? (I need to find the most tight bound!!!)
[image]

Comment: Someone else has the same homework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425922/how-can-i-figure-the-order-of-complexity

Comment: I guess it has to be something closer to O(n^2), don't know where those 2i*2i come from.

Comment: I'm not sure about that innermost loop. Is it actually constant time because it will never execute more than 20,000 times?

Comment: @Tim: was thinking of the same. But not constant time: linear if i < 20 000 and constant above. And i will eventually become lower than 20 000 because it decreases.

Comment: i think it is constant because eventually it is bounded by a constant number

Comment: 2i*2i one because of the i-=2 and the other 2i is because of the inner for loop, which is dependent in the while loop so going 2i times as the current value in the while loop

Comment: I coded it and it takes really really long to run even for n around 1000, complexity is definitely not constant.

Comment: If the inner (`k`) loop is constant the whole thing should be O(n^2). I'm not sure whether it's constant when it's linear to a point and then constant...

Comment: Why isn't it O(n^3)? can you explain me why not, and as well show me the calculation for the O(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's a pretty complex problem, and quite an enjoyable one for a homework.

First it is obvious that you have to split the problem into two parts, either if n is larger than 100 000 or not.

If n is larger than 100 000:

You will run the innermost loop maximum 20 000 times at once (because when j gets larger than 100 000, your k loop will result in 0 iterations). 
So for every simulation, for the part of n above 50 000 you will exactly perform

[image]

total loops. It gives

[image]

. You have to add the time of the calculation of the i < 50 000 (n < 100 000) part, which can be written as

[image] ,

that gives  [image] .

It means that above n = 100 000, your problem has a clear O(n) complexity with a constant part one or more magnitudes smaller than the linear one:

[image]

The tricky part arrives when you get below n = 100 000. Here you can write

[image],

which can be transformed into:

[image]

This function shows a linear increase with a squared decrease. Guess where its root is… (almost) exactly at 100 000.

Calculating the sum and leaving the O(1), O(n) and non-significant parts you get:

[image].

You can see that its cubic part is negative, so the time would go below 0 for large n-s. But you can also see that at n = 100 000, the squared part is still three times bigger than the cubic one, and the maximum of the function is at n = 200 000. So don’t worry, you won’t go into negative times, in fact, you won’t even reach the maximum of this function.

How can you interpret this? Well, in worst case, you have O(n2) complexity. But you have a higher order decrease, and for large n-s below 100 000, you can do much (max. 33%) better than the O(n2) would predict.

So to sum up:

- If n is much smaller than 100 000: O(n2)
- If n is close, but smaller than 100 000: somewhat better than O(n2)
- If n is larger than 100 000: O(n)

I ran an example to measure what's going on. I used different numbers (because your original problem would run forever), so your 100 000 threshold value is at 100 in my case. You can see that in the beginning, O(n2) works fine, then O(n2-n3) fits well the complexity, finally, above 100, we enter the linear part.

[image]

And for large n-s (still with a threshold of 100):

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. Above the threshold the `k` loop completes in constant time while the `i` and `j` loops are of order n. For large values of n, the overall function is O(n^2). Below the threshold all of the loops are of order n, making the function O(n^3). I timed the function for large values of n with a threshold of 100 and it clearly isn't linear. http://i.imgur.com/i1Fglwc.png

Comment: @Tim: it's not only the k, but the j loop that finishes in constant time for n > 10^5 ! Because only the j in range(10^5) part will give you anything (which is a constant), and the j in range(10^5,n) will do nothing! I couldn't reproduce your result, I got linear dependence as far as 10000 with a threshold of 100 (see edited answer).
On the other, note that your n^3 part is descending, because in the inner loop, large j-s will run fast, and small j-s will run slow! So you have an O(n3) dependence, but it is negative, and the leading part is only O(n2).

Comment: `for j in range(i)` will scale linearly - it does not complete in constant time. It sounds like you're using different code to the questioner.

Comment: @Tim: I still don't agree, but it is absolutely possible that you are right. You should write your solution as an answer to the OP and I will do my best to understand it.